# Zend Framework Inner Join Query

Tags: frameworks

I am not sure why Zend makes it difficult to write queries. I am from CodeIgniter background.

I want to write this query

```
SELECT tbllicenses.*, tblclients.email As clientemail FROM tbllicenses 
INNER JOIN tblclients ON tblclients.id = tbllicenses.clientid
```

Do you know how can I write this query without using "table AS t" kind of assignments ?

Comment: [Joins in Zend](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.db.select.html#zend.db.select.building.join). What reason do you have for not wanting `table AS t` aliases?

Answer (score 0):

Having table aliases is the standard way to write queries. so if you will go for zend join functions then aliases are required. Another way around is that you can pass the whole query to '$this->db->query("query....")'.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it could be:

```
class Application_Model_Soa_Service_LicenseService extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
{

    public function getLicenses()
    {
        $statementString = " ";
        $statementString .= " SELECT "; 
        $statementString .= " tbllicenses.*, ";
        $statementString .= " tblclients.email As clientemail ";
        $statementString .= " FROM tbllicenses ";
        $statementString .= " INNER JOIN tblclients ON tblclients.id = tbllicenses.clientid ";

        $statementQuery = $this->_db->prepare($statementString);
        $statementQuery->execute();

        $rowsetData = $statementQuery->fetchAll();

        return $rowsetData;
    }
}
```